# Print multiplication table of 14 from a list in which multiplication table of 12 is stored

Tags: python

I already have a list with multiplication table of 12. I have written a piece to make another list for table of 14 using previous list

```
#how to create table of any number  we created 12
table_12=[]
for i in range(1,121):
    if i % 12==0:
        table_12.append(i)
print(table_12)

#Print multiplication table of 14 from a list in which multiplication table of 12 is stored.
table_14=[]
for i in table_12:
    i=i+2    
    table_14.append(i)

print(table_14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have confused the logic here. You can't just add 2 to each element of the table of 12 to get the table of 14. Instead you want to add multiples of 2 i.e., adding 2 to the first element, 4 to the second element, 6 to the third element and so on.

`for i, j in enumerate(table_12):` returns you the index of the elements of your list `table_2` starting from 0 up to the length of `table_12` minus 1 (because the index starts from 0 in python). It also returns the actual elements of the list `table_2`. That's why you use two variables `i` and `j` so that the index goes into `i` and the actual list elements goes into `j`

Now the main logic here is to construct the elements of table of 14. This is done using `j+(i+1)*2` where `j` will be taking values 12, 24, 36, 48, ... 108, 120 and `i` will take the values 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 8, 9. The rest of the logic is already clear to you from the comments. I am directly appending to the list but you can also use an intermediate variable as `var=j+(i+1)*2` and then do `table_14.append(var)`. But you should not use the same variable `i` as it can potentially lead to some overwriting and is error prone

```
table_12=[] 
for i in range(1,121): 
    if i % 12==0: 
        table_12.append(i) 
print(table_12)

# [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120]


table_14=[] 
for i, j in enumerate(table_12):
    table_14.append(j+(i+1)*2)

print(table_14)

# [14, 28, 42, 56, 70, 84, 98, 112, 126, 140]
```

Comment: can you elaborate please? i am just a beginner

Comment: First element is 12 then you have 12 + 1*2 = 14. Second element is 24 then you have 24 + 2*2 = 28.  Third element is 36 then you have 36 + 3*2 = 42.  Fourth element is 48 then you have 48 + 4*2 = 52. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = 12
var answer1 = 0
for i in 1..<10+1
{
answer1 = table * i
print ("\(table) * \(i) = \(answer1)")
answer1 = answer1+(2*i)
print( "14 * \(i) = \(answer1)")
}
```